# Parse.com, Javascript, Tables

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform

I have a javascript table that is displaying data that is store in a parse.com server, i also have a iOS App that is also getting the same data from the same place on the iOS App it is every for row that has been selected in the table to store the object id in an NSString to be used in other like adding it a favourite column etc however on the javascript side i have not been very successful at this can one help?

iOS

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    PFObject *tempObject = [HomeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@", tempObject.objectId);
    _NameOfGame.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"NameGame"];
    _Items.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"item"];
    _Des.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"des"];
    userFirstname = [tempObject objectForKey:@"FirstName"];
    group = [tempObject objectForKey:@"group"];
    device = [tempObject objectForKey:@"Device"];
    together = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Uploaded by %@ from %@ on a %@", userFirstname, group, device];
    PFFile *video = [tempObject objectForKey:@"Video"];
    _videoUrl = video.url;
    NSLog(@"got a video %@", _videoUrl);
    _deleteObjectID = [HomeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@", _deleteObjectID);
    [self animateDetailView];}
```

Javascript

```
    var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("games");
var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
query.equalTo("group", strUser)
query.find(
{
    success: function(results)
    {        
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) 
        {
            var object = results[i];

            (function($) {
                $("#first-team-results-table").append("<tr><td>" 
                +"<input type='checkbox' data-id='" + object.id + "'/>" $(checkBox).appendTo("#modifiersDiv")
                + "</td><td>"
                    + object.get("NameGame")
                    + "</td><td>" 
                    + object.get("item") 
                    + "</td><td>" 
                    + object.get("des") 
                    + "</td></tr>");
            })(jQuery);
       }
    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
})
});
```

I have try with checkboxes in javascript but no luck

Answer (score 0):

In which way aren't you successful? What doesn't work?

Do you get the correct result at all? If not change this line

```
query.equalTo("group", strUser) && query.equalTo("month", res);
```

to

```
query.equalTo("group", strUser);
query.equalTo("month", res);
```

------------------------------------ EDIT -------------------------

I would rewrite it like this:

```
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("games"),
    query = new Parse.Query(GameScore),
    $table = $("#first-team-results-table"),
    tableString;

appendToTable = function (object) {
    tableString = "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' data-id='"+object.id+"'</td><td>"+object.get("NameGame")+"</td><td>"+object.get("item")+"</td><td>"+object.get("des")+"</td></tr>";
    $table.append(tableString);
    $(checkBox).appendTo("#modifiersDiv"); // I don't know what the checkbox-variable represents... anyway use this line to do something with it ;)
};

query.equalTo("group", strUser)
query.find({
    success: function(results){
        var object;
        for (var i = results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            object = results[i];
            appendToTable(object);
        };
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});
```

I'm not sure what you are doing here

```
$(checkBox).appendTo("#modifiersDiv")
```

but I hope it gets you in the right direction...

------------------------------------ EDIT -------------------------

okay retry, still not sure if I get what you're trying to do. The following will first display the table after fetching stuff from Parse.com and putting it to the #objectBox-div when clicking the 'more'-button

**HTML**

```
<div id="buttonShow"> <input type="submit" id="uploadPaid" value="More"/><input type="text" id="gotObject" class="textFields"/> </div>
<table id="first-team-results-table"></table>
<div id="objectBox"></div>
```

**JS**

```
(function() {
    var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("games"),
        query = new Parse.Query(GameScore),
        $table = $("#first-team-results-table"),
        $objectBox = $('#objectBox'),
        tableString,
        divString,
        ParseGames;

    appendToTable = function (object) {
        tableString = "<tr><td><input class='check' type='checkbox' data-id='"+object.id+"'</td><td>"+object.get('NameGame')+"</td><td>"+object.get('item')+"</td><td>"+object.get('des')+"</td></tr>";
        $table.prepend(tableString);
    };
    appendToDiv = function (object) {
        divString = "<p><span>"+object.get('NameGame')+"</span> <span>"+object.get('item')+"</span> <span>"+object.get('des')+"</span></p>";
        $objectBox.append(divString);
    };

    query.equalTo("group", strUser)
    query.find({
        success: function(results){
            ParseGames = results;
            for (var i = results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                appendToTable(results[i]);
            };
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });

    $("#uploadPaid").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $objectBox.html('');
        $('.check').each(function(index) {
            console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                appendToDiv(ParseGames[index]);
            };
        });
    });
})();
```

good luck ;)

Comment: Hi @Argee i cannot get the objectid for each row and store it into a var for use i have try to use checkboxes but not successful

Comment: thanks for the help the code does help somewhat however my i am try to get the value of the checkbox using this code and HTML div <id="buttonShow">
    <input type="submit" id="uploadPaid" value="More"/>
    <input type=text id="gotObject" class="textFields"/>
    </div> Javascript $("#uploadPaid").click(function () {
  event.preventDefault();
  var OBJECTIDS = $("objectBox").attr("value");
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  document.getElementById("gotObject").innerHTML = OBJECTIDS;
  })
  });

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of days look through website and trying lots of code i have finally got an answer to my question.

```
 <table id="first-team-results-table" class="table1" border="1xp" style="width:100%">
        <col width="80">
        <col width="80">
        <col width="5">
        <col width="300">
        <col width="100">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Name Of Game</th>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Video</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Group</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<script type="text/javascript">
     Parse.initialize("API1", "API2" );

var firstTeamResults = Parse.Object.extend("ukgames");
var query = new Parse.Query(firstTeamResults);
//query.equalTo("favs", id);
//"group" , group
query.descending("updateAt");
query.find({success: function(results){        
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) 
        {
            var object = results[i];

            (function($) {
                $("#first-team-results-table").append("<tr><td>" 
                    + "<input type='checkbox' class='chkNumber' value='"+object.id+"'/>"
                    + "</td><td>"
                    + object.get("NameGame") 
                    + "</td><td>" 
                    + object.get("item") 
                    + "</td><td>"
                    + object.get("des") 
                    + "</td><td>" 
                    + object.get("group") 
                    +"</td></tr>");
            })(jQuery);
       }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});
</script>
<div id="buttonShow"> 
    <input type="button" class="btnGetAll" value="More"/>
    <input type="text" id="gotObject" class="textFields"/> 
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">    
$(function () {
      $('.btnGetAll').click(function () {
        if ($('.chkNumber:checked').length) {
          var chkId = '';
          $('.chkNumber:checked').each(function () {
            chkId += $(this).val() + ",";
          });
          chkId = chkId.slice(0, -1);
          alert(chkId);
        }
        else {
          alert('Nothing Selected');
        }
      });

      $('.chkSelectAll').click(function () {
        $('.chkNumber').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
      });

      $('.chkNumber').click(function () {
        if ($('.chkNumber:checked').length == $('.chkNumber').length) {
          $('.chkSelectAll').prop('checked', true);
        }
        else {
          $('.chkSelectAll').prop('checked', false);
        }
      });

    });
</script>
```